# navigation doesn't scroll to anchor link

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, menu, navigation

i have this navigation which is driving me crazy tonight. i can't find the solution to make it work properly. i assume it has a conflict between css and js but i cant find the problem. below i'll post the code and also a codepen link:

**HTML**

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="Ilir Bajrami">



<title>New web test</title>






        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />



    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" /> 

  <!--  <link href="css/rotating-card.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->

   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 



    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



     <!--Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous"> 



</head>
<body>

     <div class="container" id="faqe1">


         <!-- MENUJA -->




         <div class="col-md-4">


       <div class="dotstyle dotstyle-tooltip">

                    <ul>
                        <li class="current"><a href="#faqe1">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#faqe2">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>    <!-- Menuja mbaron -->





       </div>

       <div class="col-md-4"></div>


         <div class="col-md-4"></div>





     </div> <!-- Kontaineri faqe1 mbaron -->



    <div class="container" id="faqe2">


        <h2>ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk
        ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk</h2>

        <h2>ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk
        ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk</h2>

        <h2>ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk
        ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk</h2>

        <h2>ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk
        ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk</h2>

        <h2>ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk
        ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk</h2>

        <h2>ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk
        ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk</h2>

        <h2>ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk
        ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk</h2>

        <h2>ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk
        ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk</h2>

        <h2>ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk
        ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk</h2>

        <h2>ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk
        ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk</h2>

        <h2>ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk
        ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk</h2>

        <h2>ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk
        ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk</h2>

        <h2>ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk
        ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk</h2>

        <h2>ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk
        ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk</h2>

        <h2>ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk
        ajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjkajfhkahfjkdhfjk</h2>




    </div> <!-- kontaineri faqe2 mbaron -->




 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/dots.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <script>
            [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.dotstyle > ul' ) ).forEach( function( nav ) {
                new DotNav( nav, {
                    callback : function( idx ) {
                        //console.log( idx )
                    }
                } );
            } );
        </script>







</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}


#faqe1 {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;



}



/* Faqe2 */


#faqe2 {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image:url("../images/Unknown-2.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;

}
/* Common styles and resets */

.dotstyle ul {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    top:25em;
    left: -8em;

    transform: rotate(90deg)


}

.dotstyle li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 16px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;




}

.dotstyle li a {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    text-indent: -999em; /* make the text accessible to screen readers */
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;


}

.dotstyle li a:focus {
    outline: none;
}

/* Individual styles and effects */



/* Tooltip */

.dotstyle-tooltip li {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease;
    transition: border-color 0.3s ease;






}

.dotstyle-tooltip li a {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 250%;
    left: 50%;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    text-indent: 0;
    line-height: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, visibility 0s 0.3s ease;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, visibility 0s 0.3s ease;




}



.dotstyle-tooltip li a::after { /* http: //cssarrowplease.com/ */
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    content: '';
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 99%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;





}

.no-touch .dotstyle-tooltip li:hover a,
.dotstyle-tooltip li.current a {
    z-index: 100;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease;




}

.dotstyle-tooltip li.current {
    border-color: #76c043;

    border: 2px solid #76c043;
}

.dotstyle-tooltip li:hover {
    z-index: 100;
}

.no-touch .dotstyle-tooltip ul:hover li.current a {
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.dotstyle-tooltip ul li.current:hover a {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**JS**

```
;( function( window ) {

    'use strict';

    function extend( a, b ) {
        for( var key in b ) { 
            if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    function DotNav( el, options ) {
        this.nav = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this._init();
    }

    DotNav.prototype.options = {};

    DotNav.prototype._init = function() {
        // special case "dotstyle-hop"
        var hop = this.nav.parentNode.className.indexOf( 'dotstyle-hop' ) !== -1;

        var dots = [].slice.call( this.nav.querySelectorAll( 'li' ) ), current = 0, self = this;

        dots.forEach( function( dot, idx ) {
            dot.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                if( idx !== current ) {
                    dots[ current ].className = '';

                    // special case
                    if( hop && idx < current ) {
                        dot.className += ' current-from-right';
                    }

                    setTimeout( function() {
                        dot.className += ' current';
                        current = idx;
                        if( typeof self.options.callback === 'function' ) {
                            self.options.callback( current );
                        }
                    }, 25 );                        
                }
            } );
        } );
    }

    // add to global namespace
    window.DotNav = DotNav;

})( window );
```

http://codepen.io/Separator/pen/bpdYGP

Comment: Please have a read of this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In the process of generating *minimal* code to reproduce the problem you may find the answer - if not, additional code in a codepen is fine.

Comment: heres the codepen link: http://codepen.io/Separator/pen/bpdYGP

Comment: anyone with a solution please ?

Comment: your codepen does not show anything.

Comment: Hi Ilir, while your question is urgent to you, please remember this is a global site and many people that could help you are simply not around right now (it's midnight here for example).  Also, your question is very difficult to read and there isn't a clear "question" other than "it doesn't work".  I briefly looked at your codepen and wasn't even sure what it was supposed to do in order to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry for insisting so much but i really dont kow how to minimize my code as it is all i need to show you what code im using. so this is the whole code which im using for my navigation which doesent scroll to the given anchor link. when i remove the css and the little script on the bottom of the html file it works but if i link the css again it doesent work even without the js script. so i think i mentioned above that the problem might be in these two files. thnx

Comment: i edited the html here and in codepen as well. i removed the js code on the bottom of the html which i dont need (it was for smooth scrolling). so now that is the code which makes the problem i think. so the css and the js on the bottom of the html...